# Unix grep is failing in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to use Unix `grep` in my ruby code which I am able to run my shell terminal but it is not working when I am calling it through my `ruby code`. Can someone help me finding the problem?

I am trying to read the lines that match the pattern that starts with `/platform/app_name` and ends with `username or service_name or hostname or port` in `config.txt` file and write them into `sub_config.txt` file. Below is the piece of code that is blocking me right now.

```
exec ("cd #{$USER_HOME}; grep -E \'(^/platform/app_name/.*/username) | (^/platform/app_name/.*/port) | (^/platform/app_name/.*/service_name) | (^/platform/app_name/.*/hostname) \' config.txt > .sub_config.txt")
```

Comment: *In what way* is it not working? When you `puts` the command instead of calling `exec` on it, what do you see? Is `$USER_HOME` an environment variable or a Ruby global? Did you mean `ENV['USER_HOME']` instead?

Comment: `$USER_HOE` is not an environment variable. It is suppose to be the path from where user is suppose to run the tool. `puts` is not printing anything.

Comment: Where is `$USER_HOME` being set? What is its value when this line of code is reached? If this line is being reached then something *should* be printed if you replace `exec` with `puts`—if not the command, then an error message. If nothing is printed then this line of code isn't being reached, which means your error is elsewhere.

Comment: @Jordan, thank you. I tried to include more `puts` for debugging purpose and looks like it is failing at the previous line which is similar to what I mentioned earlier i.e., `exec("grep -E \"/platform/app_name\" config.txt | grep \"username\" > .sub_config.txt ; echo $?")`. Looks like it is running this command successfully by creating the `txt` and returning `exit code 0`. But then erroring out by saying `org.jruby.exceptions.MainExitException: aborted`. What could be the reason? I need more direction on this.